# Select elements from python object based on name and preserving attributes

Tags: python, object, attributes

If given a python object that includes a number of attributes (e.g. "name", "score") etc. and a list, how do I select from the first object all of the instances in the first object whose attribute matches an element in the list  **while keeping the corresponding attributes?**

I know that I can use the set function, but this requires converting the object to a list and I will then lose the remaining attributes.

Here is an example from my data that demonstrates what I want to do:

```
data_1.names
#returns
   #'C9J798',
   #'O00329',
   #'O00459',
   #etc.
data_1.score
   #returns
   #'12',
   #'60',
   #'92',
   #etc
my_list=['C9J798','O00329']
selection_from_data_1=magic_function(data_1,my_list)
#selection_from_data_1 should still have all the attributes of data_1
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Well, actually I'm pretty sure I _don't_ understand your question.

Comment: Also (totally unrelated) but an object with a list of scores and a list of names (which I assume are matched by position) looks like a design smell. You should probably have something like a list of objects having each one name and one score, or dict mapping names to score, or some variant on this scheme - but well I know nothing about your use case so take this comment with a grain of salt ;)

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers  in R, it is common to have "named lists" and it is easy to then select from one list (based on its names) from another list (again based on its names). I am looking for something like that for Python. That is basically what I want to do with Python for any attribute in the attribute list.

Comment: I know nothing about R and still don't understand what you're trying to do - I mean what's your _real_ problem, not what you think the solution should be based on concepts from a different language... Looks like a XY problem to me.

Comment: The real problem is that I have an object that contains stuff in it:my_object=['Element_1','Element_2', 'Element_3', 'Element_4' etc.]. my_object has other attributes as well. I want to copy some parts of my_object to object_2, but also keep all of the other original attributes of my_objects the same. So my_object_2=['Element_1','Element_4'], but have all other attributes of object_2 be equal to object_1

Comment: A dictionary or lists of objects won't work in this context, since I have duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, based on pandas:

```
import pandas as pandas
data_1=pandas.Series([ 12, 60, 18, 92,53],index=['Title', 'C9J798', 'O00329', 'O00459','O00459'])
list_1=['C9J798','O00459']
data_2=data_1[list_1]
```